# How to return the support IE 6+ in jQuery 2.0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I use jQuery 2.0. And for my site it's more appropriate than the old version, but I need to return the support for older browsers IE, how can this be done? (Sorry for a stupid question. Did not work with it earlier)

Comment: It's not more appropriate than the old version if you need support for IE6. The [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/) says "we recommend using the 1.x version unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8 users are visiting the site". Why do you think you need 2.0?

Comment: because my boss said to use )

Comment: @GeraySuinov show him the documentation

Comment: jQuery `2.x` and `1.10.x` are feature equal. A compromis for you boss:  You could use the conditional comments of IE to use `2.x` for non IE and IE 9 or newer. And `1.10.x` for the IE 8 and older.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible because reason for 2.x version was to remove support for those ancient browsers.

From [the docs](http://jquery.com/download/)

> jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8. All the notes in the jQuery 1.9 Upgrade
>   Guide apply here as well. Since IE 6/7/8 are still relatively common,
>   we recommend using the 1.x version unless you are certain no IE 6/7/8
>   users are visiting the site. Please read the release notes carefully.

The best you can do is use the latest 1.x release and use the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to support deprecated features if you want

Comment: +1 but if i'm correct, migrate plugin will search for deprecated methods not for logic to handle old browsers

Comment: @roasted that was what I meant by `to support deprecated features if you want`