# jQuery .hover() and .click() events not working in IE 8

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jquery for a dropdown menu, and to hide an account login area on a website. It works fine in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome on both Windows and Mac, but it does not want to work in IE8. (I have not tested 9 and 10, but it has to run on 8)

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9Ceb/).

Please ignore the CSS in the fiddle - It's compressed. Obviously, the sub-nav is hidden.

HTML:

```
<header>
        <a href="/"><h1 class="logo col-4">GreyStone Power Corporation</h1></a>
        <div class="login col-4">
            <form method="post" class="login-form">
                <p>Login to view/pay your bill:</p>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="rowElem col-6"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="col-10"/></div>
                    <div class="rowElem col-6"><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="col-10"/></div>
                    <div class="rowElem col-5"><button formaction="#" class="orangeBtn">Log In <span class="arrow-right-icon"></span></button></div>
                    <div class="col-5 right inline register"><a class="block" href="#">Register</a><a class="block" href="#">Forgot Password</a></div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div><!--  End Account Login  -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="navigation col-10-exact">
                <li>Residential
                    <section class="sub-nav col-12">
                        <ul class="sub-nav-list col-3">
                            <a href="#"><li>View/Pay Bill</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Apply For Service</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Billing/Payment Options</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Pre-paid</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Rates</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Energy Savings</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Member Handbook</li></a>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="nav-info col-9 right">
                            <p>Some Text/Other stuff here.</p>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </li>
                <li>Commercial
                    <section class="sub-nav col-12">
                        <ul class="sub-nav-list col-3">
                            <a href="#"><li>View/Pay Bill</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Apply For Service</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Billing/Payment Options</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Pre-paid</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Rates</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Energy Savings</li></a>
                            <a href="#"><li>Member Handbook</li></a>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="nav-info col-9 right">
                            <p>Some Text/Other stuff here.</p>
                        </div>
                    </section></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="account col-2-exact right">
                <li>My Account <span class="icon-acct"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!--  End Navigation  -->
    </header>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".account").click(function(){
        $(".login").fadeToggle(300);
    });
    $(".navigation > li").hover(function(){
        $(this).children(".sub-nav").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: "Not working" means what - nothing happens at all? Any errors in the reported in the browser's console? The fiddle specifies jQuery 2.0.2 which doesn't support IE8 or older.

Comment: Replace your code inside the events with `alert("blah");` Then you'll know if the event is broken or the code inside it.

Comment: "Not working" means it does not work. The event does not fire. The error is "Object doesn't support this property or method" `return n||(n=x.Deferred(),"complete"===o.readyState?setTimeout(x.ready):(o.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",S,!1),e.addEventListener("load",S,!1))),n.promise(t)` is what it references.

Comment: you're using the wrong jquery include most likely. jQuery 2.x doesn't support old IE, jquery 1.1x does.

Comment: well thats weird .. it doesnt work with 2.0> . but it does work with others ..  the error message is . `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.jquery-2.0.2.js, line 1378 character 2` and `SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
_display, line 20 character 1` .

Comment: @HusseinNazzal No, it's by design. 2.0 doesn't support old versions of IE.

Comment: @KevinB thanks i didnt know that i corrected my comment :)

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3, so if IE, I need to load 1.x?

Comment: old ie, yes. Newer versions of IE will run in 2.0.3. Newer versions being IE10+

Comment: i guess what he mean is 1.x

Comment: First line of [JQuery documentation](http://jquery.com/download/) : **jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.**

Comment: @KevinB You were the first to point out the version issue. Please make an answer and I'll accept it. I added the `[if IE]` etc for the new script. Appreciate it.

Comment: I'm trying to find one of the duplicates, this has definitely been solved before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the support IE 6+ in jQuery 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210836/how-to-return-the-support-ie-6-in-jquery-2-0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 not loading jQuery 2.0 even though it's the first include and it's loaded from the same domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838288/ie8-not-loading-jquery-2-0-even-though-its-the-first-include-and-its-loaded-fr)

Comment: If you don't care about the Rep, i'll just accept Jay Huang's answer below.

Comment: that's fine with me, idc bout it.

Comment: Appreciate everyones help. Have a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using jQuery 1.x, not 2.x. They dropped support for older versions of IE (6, 7, 8) in 2.x.

Comment: Note, jquery 1.1x follows the same api and is being updated alongside 2.x, jquery didn't simply drop support for old versions of IE.

Comment: @KevinB Yep, I meant in the 2.x line. Not sure how to make that more clear in my answer.